# how to find primary key for table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a given table in MySQL called inventory.. all the descriptions in table null = 'Yes'  and default = 'Null'.  the field names in the table are inventory, items, sales and Staff.
in inventory table I have part_no, decript,on_hand,location,unitcost, discontinue..

is it correct in stating that part_no would be my primary key as this this record can not have a duplicate value.

thank you for confirming or correcting my assumption.. Is there a query that would validate this.

Comment: Can you clarify - does the table already exist, and you want to know what its primary key already is, or you are intending to _add_ a primary key and want advice on which is the correct column?

Comment: Run `DESCRIBE inventory;`?

Comment: You can check `SHOW CREATE TABLE inventory` to get the `CREATE TABLE` statement, or you can `DESCRIBE inventory`

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY`s can not have duplicate values, or `NULL` values. Yes.

Comment: sorry yes the tables exits already

Comment: and from a select or show tables none have the primary key set as yes. this would have been the easy way for me to find it.

Answer (score 1):

did you already create your table? and could find the primary key? primary key ensure unique row and restrict duplicate value. if you want to find primary key of a table use.

> SHOW KEYS FROM tablename WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0):

The below query gets the `part_no` and it's number of appearances, if you see 2 or above, then `part_no` can't be your primary key, and you have to select another or more primary keys. Make sure `part_no` **IS NOT NULL !!!** as you can't have null primary keys

```
select part_no, count(*) as appearances
from inventory
group by part_no
```

if you want to know it faster because of many rows, you run this

```
select max(appearances)
from ( select part_no, count(*) as appearances
       from inventory
       group by part_no )
```

if max is 1 you are ok. If not, add to `group by` and `select` another collumn and do the same. Then you can determine what collumn/s is/are your primary key. And with alter table, or some GUI you can change it.

Comment: just curious wouldn't I know just be describe inventory...this is why im confused since all the field names in inventory are set as NULL = yes and default = null and key = blank on all..

Comment: of course to confirm this is from tables that were sent to me for exercises in my class

Comment: if every field is null as default and they are allowed to have null values, then you can't have a primary key. I implied that you have some dummy data and try to find out if all of the rows in a specific collumn are unique. If you have to create the table and feed rows yourself, then put the primary key you think it is and try to add data. If there is any problem you will see your `insert into` will return an error